# Get Soap Messages posted on IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

How can i get soap messages posted on IP say 12.23.421.12:3759

is there any way that soap messages on this IP can be read and data can be parsed from XML.

this is the log from WIRESHARK tool, i need to parse this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlso ap.org/soap/encoding/" 
   xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSche ma-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://w ww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <huawei:setSubscriberDetails xmlns:huawei="http://business.add.gsm.rcom.com">
        <paramSubscriberDetails>
            <IMEI>355030005026 8312</IMEI>
            <IMSI >405828210239016</IMSI>
            <prepaid>true</prepaid>
            <MSISDN>919646845889</MSISDN>
        </paramSubscriberDetails>
    </huawei:setSubscriberDetails>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: What do you mean with get? Is there a service on the internet that is giving you information or are you implementing a (SOAP)service yourself that should listnen on a specific port/Ip address?

Comment: Yes there is a service that send soap messages to IP, i need to parse that message, how can i do that.

Comment: can you give an example of what you are getting from the service? Especially thats in the Soap enveloppe

Comment: Please refer to the log code that i added from wire shark .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an Service Reference to your project. This creates a class and some methods that you can use to call the soap service.

If you receive just the Soap message load it in [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) using the Load method.
because it is XML you can get your information by doing

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://yourserver.com/yourservice/1");
var body = xDoc.Element("SOAP-ENV:Body");
var huaweiSubscriberDetails = new HuaweiSubscriberDetails(){
     Imei = body.Element("IMEI").Value,
     Imsi = body.Element("IMSI").Value,
     etc...
}
```

I just did this out of my head without Visual Studio so don't pin me down on it, if it contains errors.

Comment: I cannot add a service refernce coz It's not a service actually hosted on IP, the problem is that soap messages are sent to this IP (Source IP is not fixed but destination is fixed)  you can say it's like a TCP packets that hitting on this IP every time, i need to grab these packets

Answer (score 0):

I think you need TCP Listener install on your IP:Port

[TcpListener MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)

usually SOAP Response back to caller address (SOAP Request). You do not need a TcpListener if SOAP Request coming from you. It's my guess :)